# android launch SMS intent without any recipient

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to open the Android SMS application from my application and I don't want to set any contact as a recipient, How?

Comment: Please always post the stack trace from your logcat when it crashes.  We're not going to debug it without that.

Comment: @GabeSechan I am not asking about the exception solution , i know where is the wrong as i told you , i am asking about something else, read the question please

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello World!");  
startActivity(intent);
```

#### note

this way doesn't need any permission in `Manifest`