# start sms intent without recipients

Tags: android

I want to open the sms intent without predefined recipients, this is my code.

```
Uri myuri = Uri.parse("to:");
Intent smsintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, myrui);
smsintent.putExtra("sms_body", "new sms here boddy");  
startActivity(smsintent);
```

i get exception that

```
myuri can't be parsed
```

why that?

Comment: have u seen this question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860581/android-launch-sms-intent-without-any-recipient/14860707#14860707

Comment: Your URI should be `Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:");`

Comment: yes that question helped me, thank you guys

Comment: you have to select one answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this.

```
Use Uri myuri = Uri.parse("smsto:"); instead of Uri.parse("to:");
```

or

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "new sms here boddy");  
startActivity(sendIntent);
```